# Clean url in django app. without ?page=1 pattern

Tags: python, regex, django, listview, url

I want to have my url pattern like the below pattern:

```
host:8000/archive/2/
```

I define `page_kwarg` in my view but I still receive: `host:8000/en/2`

Code form main **url.py** file:

```
url(_(r'^archive'), include('events.urls_archive', namespace='archive')),
```

**start edit1**
and link form main site to my app:

```
<a href="{% url 'archive:list' %}" title="{% trans 'Archive' %}">
    {% trans 'Archive' %}
</a>
```

**end edit1**

**start edit2**

This is the url in my app **urls_archive.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^/(?P<page>\d+)/$', ArchiveListView.as_view(), name="list"),
    url('^/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)$', ArchiveDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
]
```

**end edit2**

The code for my view:

```
class ArchiveListView(ListView):
    model = Booking
    queryset = Booking.objects.filter(period__type='archive').order_by('-date_start')
    paginate_by = 80
    page_kwarg = 'page'
```

Here is my template code:

```
        {% if is_paginated %}
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="/{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="arrow left"><h4>Previous</h4></a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="arrow header"><h4>Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</h4></span>
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="/{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="arrow right"><h4>Next</h4></a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
```

Please provide any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page_kwarg` sets the key that the page number is passed in as. It doesn't affect how it is used in the page. For some reason, you are outputting that directly as `/{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}`, which resolves to just `/2`. You should output it in the same format as it is passed in:

```
?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number}}
```

**Edit**

If you want your page number to be specified as part of the path arguments, you should use the `url` tag, like any other URL:

```
{% url 'archive' page=page_obj.previous_page_number %}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but now I have `archive?page=2` instead of `archive/2`.

Comment: I don't see where you're including any information.

Comment: Please check now.